# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (array)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, jsx

I have this async function that is fetching data from the API but when I use the data it gets a type error of undefined with movies array. But then I use "&&" to tell it that if it's empty then don't execute the block but it still gives the error. I have done it by the ternary operator too but still the same.

Here is the use effect hook which is fetching data from API

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {

   async function fetchData() {

     const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
     setMovies(request.data.results);
     console.log(movies);
     return request;
   }

   fetchData();
}, [fetchUrl]);
```

And here is the code for that element

```
{movies &&
    <div id="film-row">
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[0].poster_path}`} />
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[1].poster_path}`} />
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[2].poster_path}`} />
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[3].poster_path}`} />
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[4].poster_path}`} />
      <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies[5].poster_path}`} />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd really recommend using `Array.map()` to build up your components rather than hard-coding the indices like that. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components

Comment: This is just for testing. I will use .map for sure. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a `?` to your tags like this

```
  <FilmCard img={`${base_url}${movies?.[0]?.poster_path}`} />
```

or
change your conditional rendering to :

{movies.length &&

Comment: thanku .lenght solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

It can be tough to remember what values are coerced to true or false by JavaScript. In this case, an empty array ([]) is actually a "truthy" value ([see MDN for examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)), so your FilmCard elements will be rendered unwantedly.

Either change your conditional to account for this:

```
{movies.length &&
```

Or initialize `movies` as a "falsy" value:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do fetch data like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
    const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
     setMovies(request.data.results); 
  })()
},[fetchUrl])
```

And you should check if movies is not null.
in the return add

```
{movies.length > 0 && // What you want to do with movies.}
```

Comment: > 0 is redundant here movies.length is enough, also be aware of in some cases this code case returns unexpected result so suggesting use here {movies.length ? () : null}

Answer (score 0):

The object is being read before the response. Why use async await when you can use "then."

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get(fetchUrl).then(res => {
  setMovies(res);
})
}, []);
```

More on the subject here: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro